# How to convert json's array into array with swift

Tags: swift

I have this array `items`

```
var items: [String] = []
```

And `prizes[0]` is `__NSCFDictionary`

And one of it key-value pair is

key: `to_prizes`

value:

```
Optional(<__NSCFArray 0x787dbfb0>(
94761178,
71959593,
36665808,
54185273,
18953944,
347,
790
)
```

How could I make the swift string array `items` to be [`94761178`,....,`790`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this path like this:

```
let prizesDictionary = prizes[0] as NSDictionary
let toPrizesArray = prizesDictionary["to_prizes"] as NSArray
var items: [String] = toPrizesArray as [AnyObject] as [String]
```